# SQLite only works in memory and for backups

Tags: c++, sqlite

All of this works great on Windows (exact same code). Not so much on OS X. I'm aware of other issues with iOS and SQLite, but this is just with OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.4.1.

I've got a SQLite database that will work just fine for in-memory databases, but not when writing out to a file. The strange thing is that I can take the in-memory DB and back it up to a file just fine.

But wait, there's more...

I can create tables on a *file DB* and they correctly show up when I view them. However, when I try a `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master`, it returns nothing. If I try to insert or query anything from a table, I get a table not found error. It's like it can't even find what it just did.

For example:

```
std::string filename = "test.db";
sqlite3* database = nullptr;
sqlite3_open(filename.c_str(), &database);
// ...
// Create tables...works
// Query from sqlite_master...broken
```

Doing the same thing with `:memory:` works fine though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `sqlite3_open` call looks correct. However, I am unable to say anything about the rest of your code ...

Comment: I use SQLite on OSX without incident, but not from C++ or Obj-C (my apps are in a different language, so I've not tried). I'm guessing that the problem is not SQLite itself or OSX…

Comment: You declare `database`, but you pass `&_database` to `sqlite3_open()`. Please copy-and-paste exact code so we don't have to guess how else the code you show us differs from the code you're using.

Comment: I found that the problem actually originated from linking in the Poco::Data::SQLite library even though I wasn't using it. This seems to be a bug there.

Answer (score 0):

This simple C program works just fine. Check for anything you might be doing differently.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(void)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int res;

    res = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    assert(res == SQLITE_OK);

    res = sqlite3_exec(db, "create table if not exists tab(col)", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    assert(res == SQLITE_OK);
    res = sqlite3_exec(db, "insert into tab values('Hello, world!')", NULL, NULL, NULL);
    assert(res == SQLITE_OK);

    res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select * from tab", -1, &stmt, NULL);
    assert(res == SQLITE_OK);
    assert(sqlite3_column_count(stmt) >= 1);
    res = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    assert(res == SQLITE_ROW);
    printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```